# best_in_place gem initializing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

rails 3.2.11

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "best_in_place"
```

aplication.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require best_in_place
```

post.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= best_in_place @post, :title %>
```

inline form viewed but i got js exception and nothing fired on enter, loose focus etc. traceback:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u jquery.js:525
jQuery.extend.parseJSON jquery.js:525
BestInPlaceEditor.setHtmlAttributes best_in_place.js:265
BestInPlaceEditor.forms.input.activateForm best_in_place.js:309
BestInPlaceEditor.activate best_in_place.js:54
BestInPlaceEditor.clickHandler best_in_place.js:260
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3046
elemData.handle
```

lines at jquery.js

```
if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
  return window.JSON.parse( data );
```

how i can fix this?

**upd** problem solved. do same changes but all works fine. magic ;)

Comment: I found that adding :html_attrs => {:class=>"dummy"} to the best_in_place tag resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Using the git version of the gem resolved it in my case.

`gem 'best_in_place', github: 'bernat/best_in_place'`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

to

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

Comment: no, same problem, i think your code identical or what difference?