# Rails rest in peace gem - how to use in each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using the Rest in place gem: https://github.com/janv/rest_in_place.

How to use it correctly inside of an each loop? More specifically, for a belongs_to relationship ?

For Example, User `has_many :fee_agreements` and FeeAgreement `belongs_to :user`

How to utilize the edit in place feature to update the fee_agreement "loan_amount" here?

```
<tbody>
<% @user.fee_agreements.each do |fa| %>

<tr>
  <td><%= fa.user_id %></td>
  <td><%= fa.loan_id %></td>
  <td id="<%=  dom_id(fa)  %>"><span class="rest-in-place" data-formtype="input" data-attribute="loan_amount"><%= fa.loan_amount %></span></td>
  #above is the line in question
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

Console output:

```
 Started PUT "/users/51" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-19 00:19:29 -0400
 Processing by UsersController#update as JSON
 Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"xxx=", "fee_agreement"=>{"loan_amount"=>"998988"}, "id"=>"51"}
```

I do have a separate controller for FeeAgreements which "builds" for the user..

```
def create
  @fee_agreement = current_user.fee_agreements.build(:loan_id => params[:loan_id])
  if @fee_agreement.save
    redirect_to fee_agreements_path
  else
    redirect_to index_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out:

instead of rest_in_place use [Best in Place](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing) gem

after some initial setup as described in screencast you can use it by

```
<tbody>
<% @user.fee_agreements.each do |fa| %>

<tr>
  <td><%= fa.user_id %></td>
  <td><%= fa.loan_id %></td>
  <td><%= beast_in_place fa.loan_amount %></span></td>
  #above is the line in question
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: seems better even though there were some jQuery/initialization problems with it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466158/best-in-place-gem-initializing   I used the :html_attrs => {:class=>"dummy"}  to solve it